# Liferay + Struts2 There is no Action mapped for action name default.

Tags: struts2, liferay

I am using Liferay6 with Struts2 .

This is the LOgin.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Struts 2 Login Application!</title>
</head>
<body>
<s:form action="login" method="POST" validate="true">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
Login
</td>
</tr>
<s:actionerror />
<s:fielderror />
<s:textfield name="username" label="Login name"/>
<s:password name="password" label="Password"/>
<s:submit value="Login" align="center"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is struts.xml  file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/view">
         <action name="login"
            class="net.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/view.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

This is exception stacktrace

```
9:51:52,109 ERROR [Jsr168Dispatcher:27] Could not find action
There is no Action mapped for action name default. - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:177)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:61)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:39)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:47)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:36)
    at org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher.serviceAction(Jsr168Dispatcher.java:446)
    at org.apache.struts2.portlet.dispatcher.Jsr168Dispatcher.render(Jsr168Dispatcher.java:323)
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:100)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:93)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:72)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:530)
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:639)
```

Comment: What page url where you get this error? sitename/youapp/view/login.action?

Answer (score 0):

`There is no Action mapped for action name default.`

But your action name **login**

`<action name="login" class="net.LoginAction">`

Your actions url must be `sitename/youapp/view/login.action`

In addition for loggining your hava two actions.

```xml
    <action name="prepareLogin" class="net.LoginAction" method="input">
        <result name="success">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

`prepareLogin` - this action only view login page

```xml
    <action name="login" class="net.LoginAction"  method="execute">
        <result name="success">/Welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

`login` - this action get loggining